# Can LibGDX do relative rendering when a sprite is a child of another?

Tags: libgdx

With frameworks such as Cocos2d and SpriteKit, it is possible to add a sprite/label/node as a child of another. If a node is rotated, then the rendering of its children will be affected by such rotation and so on throughout the node tree.

Can this be achieved in LibGDX?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be achieved using **Scene2d**.

[Wiki Entry](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d):

> - Rotation and scale of a group is applied to all child actors. Child actors always work in their own coordinate system, parent transformations are applied transparently.

Comment: But an actor can't contain another actor - the only one who can do this is the "Group" actor. What if I want a sprite to contain another sprite that contains some labels and so on?

Comment: I guess that one could create a custom "Sprite" class that encapsulates a Group containing one single scene2D sprite child. But constructing one Group per sprite might be overkill. Would there be a simpler way?

Comment: Hope this will work out for me , and when it does i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a scene Graph and this is provided as mentioned in the Scene2d api. What you do is, you create a group, add your sprite, e.g. a tank, add a label and other stuff. Then you can rotate the group and all children will be rotated with it. If you want just rotate the tank this is still possible but in most cases you just transform the root node, a Group.

The sprite itself is leave and if you won't to transform some sprites together you just put them in the same group and apply the transform their.

If you wanna create several 100 Sprites with a label together you could do this: Implement a RefNode which references a Group. Create a group where you add a sprite and a label. (if you wanna change the label text you would have to store it separately and update it before you actually render the referenced group) Then you can apply all the transformation to the RefNode.

Comment: Suppose I want to make a chain of a 100 sprites. In cocos2d, it is easy to just do [sprite addChild:anotherSprite] 100 times. But in LibGDX, I'd have to make 100 Groups to add one into another and so on right? The wiki says that it is a performance bottleneck to make even a few dozens. A literally want each sprite/label to act like a group - that is, like a Cocos2d node.

Comment: I updated my answer somewhat. The question remains if the scene2d API is correct. It's nice to use it, I implemented a simple game with it (just some textures and animation) but eventually you have to implement your own small scene graph. This would have the benefit to provide more flexibility for your game. With the Actor Interface you could also implement a bridge between scene2d and your scene graph.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't I need a 100 RefNodes anyway?

Comment: Yes of course but if you want a 100 transformations then you need to store them somewhere. But then at least the expensive image data is only loaded once.

Comment: What I meant was, if a RefNode contains a Group, 100 RefNodes would mean I'd have 100 Groups no? And the wiki seems to be against that many.

Comment: I would implement RefNode without a group

Comment: Ok, so a 100 RefNodes reference one and only one group. But if a node is a child of another node, I would need two Groups right?

Comment: A is parent of B. A can be a group or an actor you implemented yourself to reference B. If B references C then B must be a Group or another implementation which can reference a node.

Comment: Yeah, so if I make a chain of 100 nodes (one node a parent of another and so on), 99 of them would have to be groups in order to achieve the same effect you get from cocos2d, but isn't the wiki against making so many groups?

Comment: I guess so. May be the libgdx devs thought 100 transformations is not something you do every day?

Comment: Do you have any tutorial or code for the above discussed Q&A .

Comment: No sorry, but the linked wiki entry from Lestat should give you a head start(?)

Comment: I checked it, we cannot add sprite, either we can add actor, but i needed the operations on sprite.